# Convert TO Local Time Zone

Tags: sql, oracle, time, plsql, zone

I am trying to get local time stamp from available TimeZone Name and timezone.

TimeZone ='19:59:00'
TimeZoneName ='EST'

Needed Local time  ?

Comment: select localtimestamp from dual?  Your question is unclear...

Comment: I need to find out the localtime stamp according to local time zone suppose 'EST' or  'Asia/Bangkok' is a zone , what will be the local time ?

Comment: what is your 9time zone

Comment: mine is EST for now but it could be any of available time zones

Answer (score 1):

NEW_TIME is an USA-centric function and is no good in the rest of the wider world.  You can get what you want with the following:

```
DECLARE
  l_time CONSTANT TIMESTAMP(8) WITH TIME ZONE := TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( '01/01/2017 19:59:00 ' || TZ_OFFSET('EST'), 'fmDDfm/MM/YYYY fmHH24fm:MI:SS TZH:TZM' );
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line( 'EST Time->' || l_time );
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Local Time->' || l_time AT TIME ZONE SESSIONTIMEZONE );    -- Assumes session is local
END;
```

Note that TIMESTAMP must contain a date context

```
Output:
EST Time->01-JAN-17 07.59.00.00000000 PM -05:00
Local Time->02-JAN-17 08.59.00.000000000 AM +08:00
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle we have New_Time() function to converts a date from time zone1 to a date in time zone2.

**EXAMPLE**

```
select NEW_TIME (sysdate, 'EST', 'MST')
from dual
```

Above query will Convert from EST TO MST

**Output**

```
December, 09 2015 16:07:42
```

FOr More [refer](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2036.htm) and [refer1](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/new_time.php)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `EST`?

```
SELECT tzabbrev, TZ_OFFSET(tzname), tzname  
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES tz 
WHERE tzabbrev = 'EST'
ORDER BY 1,2,3;

TZABBREV    TZ_OFFSET(TZNAME)   TZNAME
EST +10:00  Australia/Brisbane
EST +10:00  Australia/Lindeman
EST +10:00  Australia/Queensland
EST +10:30  Australia/Broken_Hill
EST +10:30  Australia/Yancowinna
EST +11:00  Australia/ACT
EST +11:00  Australia/Canberra
EST +11:00  Australia/Hobart
EST +11:00  Australia/LHI
EST +11:00  Australia/Lord_Howe
EST +11:00  Australia/Melbourne
EST +11:00  Australia/NSW
EST +11:00  Australia/Sydney
EST +11:00  Australia/Tasmania
EST +11:00  Australia/Victoria
EST -05:00  America/Cayman
EST -05:00  America/Detroit
EST -05:00  America/Fort_Wayne
EST -05:00  America/Grand_Turk
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Indianapolis
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Marengo
EST -05:00  America/Indiana/Vevay
EST -05:00  America/Indianapolis
EST -05:00  America/Iqaluit
EST -05:00  America/Jamaica
EST -05:00  America/Kentucky/Louisville
EST -05:00  America/Louisville
EST -05:00  America/Montreal
EST -05:00  America/New_York
EST -05:00  America/Panama
EST -05:00  America/Thunder_Bay
EST -05:00  Canada/Eastern
EST -05:00  EST
EST -05:00  EST5EDT
EST -05:00  Jamaica
EST -05:00  US/East-Indiana
EST -05:00  US/Eastern
EST -05:00  US/Michigan
EST -06:00  America/Cancun
EST -06:00  America/Chicago
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Knox
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Petersburg
EST -06:00  America/Indiana/Vincennes
EST -06:00  America/Knox_IN
EST -06:00  America/Managua
EST -06:00  America/Rankin_Inlet
EST -06:00  CST
EST -06:00  US/Central
EST -06:00  US/Indiana-Starke
EST -07:00  America/Cambridge_Bay
```